# Selenium Ebay Script

Tags: selenium

I have logged into Ebay and want to click the hyperlink of 'My collections' which is under "G'day [username]". The issue is now I can not find the element of 'My collections'. The error message is "Unable to locate element: (//li[@id='gh-ucol']/a)

Please refer to the below steps how I replicate:

- Open Ebay via Firefox
- Click Log in hyperlink
- Enter the user name password then click log in button
- Click "G'day [username]"
- Select 'My Collection' from the droplist

This is my Selenium Java Script:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;




public class KevinTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.ebay.com.au");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(20);



driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
Thread.sleep(100);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@placeholder='Email or username'])[2]")).sendKeys("my@username");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@placeholder='Password'])[1]")).sendKeys("mypassword");
driver.findElement(By.id("sgnBt")).click();
boolean tf;
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id("errf")).getText();    
    tf = true;
 }catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
    tf = false;
 }

if (tf == true) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect Password");
    driver.close();
}else {
    System.out.println("Log in successfully");
}

driver.findElement(By.id("gh-eb-u")).click();
Thread.sleep(100);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@id='gh-ucol']/a)")).click();
}}
```

Comment: Please be aware you are sharing your email/password combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Its a good practice to use implicit wait after initiating the driver.

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   ```
2. Use the below id for the 'Click "G'day [username]'.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("gh-ug")).click();
   ```
3. Use the below xpath for collection.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@id="gh-ucol"]/a")).click();
   ```

Since we have used implicit wait you can remove all other thread.sleeps. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry How can I accept your answer cos I am new here:)